# iOS: Is it possible to access foreground/background and on/off events of third-party apps from another app?

Tags: ios, kernel, hook

I am currently making an iOS app that can track events such as when another third-party app is opened, is in the foreground, is in the background, and is closed.

The only way I see this possible is to use kernel API hooks to intercept event messages between the other third-party apps and the system, but is it feasible?

EDIT: Most preferably to use technology and methods that would allow the app to be published on the iTunes store and does not infringe Apple terms of use (eg. jailbreaking).

Comment: Simple. Is your app in the foreground? If so, the other apps, if running, must be in the background. If your app is not in the foreground, then there is no need to know what state the other apps are in, right? Or is there more to what you wish to do than this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, at least via public APIs. Your app is sandboxed, and it can't get outside it's sandbox.

Comment: The app needs to track apps individually to see specifically which third-party app is called to the foreground and sent to the background or disabled.  It doesn't need to track its own activity - just the events of other apps.

EDIT: So far, it does not seem feasible with public APIs, outside of Apple.